# Adjusting the p-value of a strategy for number of parameters

Tags: backtesting, optimization, sharpe-ratio, statistical-significance

Let's say I have some metric and I'm trying to evaluate whether it's predictive with respect to returns.  I plan to only take trades where the value of the metric is above a certain threshold, such that I'm in the asset only part of the time.

I then want to compare the returns of the strategy to the overall returns of the asset.  Below is an example where I'm taking trades if the metric `x` is above a threshold value.  The red shaded region represents trades actually taken and the `y` values represent returns (scale is ignored for simplicity).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

np.random.seed(0)

cov = np.array([[1,0.4],
                [0.4,1]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal((0,0), cov, size=100)

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

threshold = 1.0
upper_x = x[x > threshold]
upper_y = y[x > threshold]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(upper_x, upper_y, color="red")
plt.axvline(threshold, color="red")

x_lim = plt.gca().get_xlim()
margins = plt.gca().margins()

plt.axvspan(threshold, x_lim[1]+margins[0], color="red", alpha=0.2)
plt.xlim(x_lim)
plt.show()


population_mean = y.mean()
subset_mean = upper_y.mean()
ttest = ttest_ind(upper_y, y, alternative="greater")
statistic = ttest.statistic
pval = ttest.pvalue

print("overall mean:", population_mean)
print("subset mean:", subset_mean)
print("p-value: ", pval)
print("statistic:", statistic)
```

[image]

```
overall mean: 0.07900435132575541
subset mean: 0.4628558666591004
p-value:  0.08187310219812942
implied z-score: 1.3925820821961334
```

In the example, the mean of the subset is higher than the overall mean, but with a p-value of 0.08, I'd have to decide whether it's worth trading the strategy.

As an aside, I've typically used Sharpe ratio and other custom metrics to evaluate strategies in backtesting, but I'm trying to use p-value more.  Technically, Sharpe is basically just a Z-score, so I could convert it to a p-value, but a given strategy will not always have a position and Sharpe might be deflated because of that.  I could use something like in-sample Sharpe, but I think p-value is a little more intuitive and straight to the point to tell me how likely it is I'm looking at something that represents an actual edge.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter which is used as long as I can rationally adjust the value based on the number of metrics I'm using.

Regarding strategy evaluation, a couple things I'm already aware of:

- **Multiple hypothesis testing:** As I understand it, the idea is to multiply the p-value by the number of hypotheses tested, however, I don't think that viewing this as a multiple hypothesis test is appropriate because there will always be a degree of overlap between thresholds in that the most extreme value(s) will always be included.  If one threshold leads to 20 trades and another threshold leads to 21 trades, 20 of which are from the first group, it doesn't make sense to call those different hypotheses.
- **Akaike Information Criterion and Bayesian Information Criterion:** If I understand these correctly, they are more for comparing models rather than looking at absolute probabilities, however, the idea of adjusting a baseline probability/likelihood for model complexity is what I'm looking for.

The example above is for a single metric/parameter, but I'm wondering if there are any other methods I can use to adjust a p-value (or Z-score) for the complexity of the metrics I use to trade on that would work for a varying number of metrics, sample size, etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is the `programming` tag relevant here?

Comment: Weird, it looks like it changes python to programming automatically.

Comment: My point is that the question does not seem to be about programming as defined in the tag description.